# Share link for a photo from icloud or photos app

Tags: icloud, photos, sharing

There used to be a way to get a direct link to a photo in iCloud and share it.

I was surprised to see this still isn't possible from the photos app so i went to the iCloud website and i still can't get a direct link to an image.

Is it possible to get a direct link to photo in iCloud that i can share with anyone?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a public album and share the link to it to anyone, but not to a single image. One solution could be to create a album for each image.

[iCloud: Create a shared album](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12068)

You can also place the image file in iCloud drive, view the file in a browser and copy the link to it.