# Can I hotlink to a photo in an album in iCloud?

Tags: icloud, album

Can I hotlink to a photo in an album in iCloud? I need to insert the direct URLs into spreadsheets.

Comment: Use Google photos instead. It does this.

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235781/88313) but it doesn't have an accepted answer yet.

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate... trying to close. - Seems like I can't. Just delete... hm...

Comment: I tried the normal sharing icon, I tried googling, I tried looking out my window to see if any Apple employees would pass by and tell me/fix the problem. Anyhows, I guess that using Google photos or some other service is the only good workaround. I did try Dropbox but they "highjack" the shared links (it seems to be possible by adding dl=1 at the end though but I doubt this is really a well supported feature)